# Probability with numbers in [0,1] and sum of their squares

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

We choose two points in $[0,1]$.

(A) Calculate the probability the sum of their squares is less than $1$.

(B) Calculate the probability the sum of their squares is equal to $1$.

Let $x,y \in [0,1]$. I want to find $P(\{{x^2+y^2<1}\})$ for (A) and $P(\{{x^2+y^2=1}\})$ for (B).

For (A) I found $P(\{{x^2+y^2<1}\})=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

If I want to find $P(\{{x^2+y^2\le1}\})$, it is also $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$? If I want $P(\{{x^2+y^2>1}\})$, is $P(\{{x^2+y^2>1}\})=1-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$? I can't find $P(\{{x^2+y^2=1}\})$ for part (B).

Comment: Assuming independence, which you have in the rest of the question, $P(\{{x^2+y^2=1}\})=0$ as it is the area of the arc of the quarter circle divided by $1$